# Reusing a Netty 4.0 AttributeKey name OR unregistering a Netty UniqueName

Tags: java, osgi, netty

Is it possible to "undefine" a Netty AttributeKey or UniqueName instance?

I have Netty 4.0.8 deployed in an OSGi container, and I have a class in separate bundle which defines a `static final AttributeKey`.

The problem is that reloading or redeploying that bundle causes that class to be loaded again (and static initialization to happen again), so the `AttributeKey` constructor call blows up since the string used to identify it is already present in the map of in-use names from the last time the bundle started up.

Appending a random number to the end of the `String` argument to the constructor avoids a collision, but this causes names to accumulate in the `AttributeKey` class's `UniqueName` map.

My question then is about the best practice for defining `AttributeKey`s in a class that may be dynamically reloaded. Specifically: what is it? Do I need manage my own pool of `AttributeKey` instances?

For reference, the ugly random number hack looks like this:

```java
private static final AttributeKey<ChannelGroup> PAGE_GROUP = 
        new AttributeKey<>("MyOtherwiseUniqueString" + new Random().nextInt());
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting this problem.  I've just filed an issue: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1824

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this bug has been scheduled for Netty 5.  Now you have to use a factory method instead of constructor to get an `AttributeKey`:

```
private static final AttributeKey<Boolean> KEY =
        AttributeKey.valueOf(MyHandler.class, "MY_KEY");
```

It always returns a singleton, so you don't need to worry about class loader issue anymore.  For more information, read [this pull request](https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/1949).